# Using "require" in Directive to require a parent Controller

Tags: angularjs

I try to "require" a parent controller (not directive) but AngularJS returns an exception. The code is like this:

## JS

```
app.controller("myController", function ($scole) {
    ...
});

app.directive("myDirective", function ($q) {
    return {
        require: "^myController",
        template: "",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, myCtrl) {
            ...
        }
    };
});
```

## HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myController as myCtrl">
    ...
        <div my-directive>...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

## Error

> Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'myController', required by
>   directive 'myDirective', can't be found!

Why?
Maybe, `require` property must be reference to a controller of **directive**?

Thanks

Comment: You are correct that the `require` property is for referencing the controllers of other directives.

Comment: I had suspected, but could not find anything in the official documentation to give me this certainty.
Thanks Alex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Require is  of using other directives controllers in another directive , please refer the below example

```
var App =  angular.module('myApp',[]);

//one directive

App.directive('oneDirective',function(){

  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller:function($scope){

       $scope.myName= function(){
            console.log('myname');
          }

         }
    }

});

   //two directive

  App.directive('twoDirective',function(){

  return {
      require:'oneDirective' //one directive used,
      link : function(scope,ele,attrs,oneCtrl){
         console.log(oneCtrl.myName())
     }

   }

  })
```

Comment: Do these two directives need to be related to each other? Like do they need share a common parent or something.

Answer (score 9):

Notation `require: "^myController"` means that your directive will try to access another directive called `myController` and defined on some of the ancestor tags as `my-controller` attribute or `<my-controller>` tag. In your case you don't have such directive, hence the exception.

This is not very conventional what you are trying to do, but if you *really* want to require outer controller in your directive you can require `ngController`:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function($q) {
    return {
        require: "^ngController",
        template: "",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, myCtrl) {
            // ...
            console.log(myCtrl);
        }
    };
});
```

However, this is not very good idea. I can't imagine why you might need it like this. I would recommend to look into [`scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) configuration properties and how you can pass executable function references into your directive from outer controller.

```
<div my-directive some-callback="test()"></div>
```

and in directive define scope:

```
scope: {
    someCallback: '&'
}
```

where in controller you would have `$scope.test = function() {};`. Then you would not need to require controller explicitly in directive.

Comment: Yeah the require feature isn't really for what you're trying to do @riofly. It's for directives to talk to other directives through a little controller API. For example, if you needed your directive to work with the `ngModel` directive then you'd use this feature to require `ngModel`'s controller so you can call stuff on it like a little API. If you need to share data between directives and controllers, look into services and the various isolate scope binding syntaxes.