# Angular require Controller from RouteProvider

Tags: angularjs

Having the following structure:

```
// routes:

...

angular.module("MyModule")
.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/index",
        {
            "templateUrl": "parent-template.html",
            "controller": "ParentController",
            "controllerAs": "parentController"
        })

// directives
   .directive("myDirective",function(){
    return {
        "restrict": "E",
        "templateUrl": "directive-template.html",
        "controller": "DirectiveController",
        "controllerAs": "ctrl",
        "require": "^parentController"

    };
})
```

I am getting the following Error:

> > Controller 'ParentController', required by directive 'myDirective', can't be found!

The controller of course is defined in:

angular.module("MyModule")
     .controller("ParentController", function(){...});

Also the `parent-template.html` works.

I would like to pass the `parentController` to the `link` function of `myDirective`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30673502/2263683) can guide you to your solution.

> Notation `require: "^myController"` means that your directive will try
>   to access another directive called `myController` and defined on some
>   of the ancestor tags as `my-controller` attribute or `<my-controller>`
>   tag. In your case you don't have such directive, hence the exception.
>
> if you *really* want to require outer controller in your directive you
>   can require `ngController`