# Can I make this Isolated Scope Directive work with my Parent Scope?

Tags: angularjs

I looked at the documentation about `scope` but can't wrap my head around it. My directive is a loading-overlay with an isolated scope. I tried both `scope: true` and `scope: false`, but neither has the desired effect. On top of that I read that `scope: {}` is considered to be best practice.

I understand that you can pass values to the isolated scope via `@` or `=`, but that's not what I need (I think?). What i need, is to add my directive(=the overlay) to the parent-scope when clicking on a breadcrumb.

**tl;dr**: My overlay doesn't appear when I navigate with the breadcrumbs.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="myApp">
            <ui-breadcrumbs template-url="Scripts/app/uiBreadcrumbs.tpl.html" displayname-property="data.breadcrumbLabel" abstract-proxy-property="data.breadcrumbProxy"></ui-breadcrumbs>

            <div loading-Overlay></div> **This is my isolated scope**

            <div id="MainBody" ui-view="main">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
</div>
```

This is the directive:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular
        .module("myApp")
        .directive("loadingOverlay", ["$http", "$timeout",
            function ($http, $timeout) {
                return {
                    restrict: "A",
                    replace: true,
                    templateUrl: "./Scripts/app/loading.overlay.html",
                    scope: {},
                    link: function (scope, element) {

                            scope.isRouteLoading = false;
                            scope.isRouteStillLoading = false;

                            scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function () {
                                scope.isRouteStillLoading = true;
                                scope.isRouteLoading = true;
                                element.addClass("show");
                            });
                            scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
                                scope.isRouteStillLoading = false;
                                scope.isRouteLoading = false;
                                $timeout(function () {
                                    if (scope.isRouteStillLoading)
                                        scope.isRouteLoading = true;
                                    element.removeClass("show");
                                }, 500);
                            });

                            scope.$watch(scope.isRouteLoading,
                                function (value) {
                                    return value ? element.addClass("show") : element.removeClass("show");
                                });
                       }
                };
            }]);

})();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using "require" in Directive to require a parent Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673459/using-require-in-directive-to-require-a-parent-controller)

Comment: I tried using `require` now but it doesn't work either (the loading overlay disappears)

Comment: Can you please create a JSFiddle of your code?